# Combinations and Permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many arrangements of the letters in DIGITAL have two consecutive I’s?

I know this is a type combination, permutation problem but i'm a little unclear how to start with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Glue the I's together to make a single "letter."

**A less nice way:** The position of the left-hand $I$ can be chosen in $6$ ways. Once this position is chosen, the position of the other I is determined. That leaves $5$ empty slots, which can be filled with distinct letters chosen from D, G, T, A, L in ??? ways.

Comment: The answer is $6!$. The quick way, we have $6$ "letters" (counting the double I as a single letter), so $6!$ or $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}\cdots \binom{1}{1}$ (same). The longer way gives $6(5!)=6!$. Your calculation gives **all** $7$-letter words using our letters, and forgets about the consecutive I's condition.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at it like this: the two 'I's are always going to be together so we treat them as a single letter. So now we can calculate the possible arrangements of DIGTAL that is 6!.